# random variables (X,Y) have the following joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification, random-variables

Let the random variable $(X,Y)$ have the following joint PDF

$$
f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 2x^{-(2x+y)}, & x>0, y>0\\
                                0,            & \text{otherwise} \end{matrix}\right\|.
$$

Please find

1. the joint cumulative distribution function (joint CDF) $F(x, y)$ and
2. the probability $\mathbb{P}[Y \leq X]$.

Comment: What is it you don't understand about the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**
$$
F(x,y) = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x, Y \leq y] = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y f(x,y) dxdy
$$

and
$$
\mathbb{P}[Y \leq X] = \iint_{y \leq x} f(x,y) dxdy
$$